# Error "Failed to load properties file for project 'MJAndroid'" in eclipse

Tags: android

I have Downloaded an example "MJAndorid" from the O'reilly.
But after importing the project into workspace, m getting the below error log:

```
Failed to load properties file for project 'MJAndroid'
```

I am not able to apply the build target, Google API version 3 , in this case.
Also, by clicking on Android in the properties window of the project, I'm geting "The currently displayed page contains invalid values".

Can someone please suggest anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac with Eclipse and the Android AVD exited

1. I deleted all projects in my workspace (backup first!)
2. recreated it with the same workspace name and
3. finally restarted eclipse and a new project setup works fine without the "Failed to load properties.." msg.